# Lines in ggplot order

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

From library `mgcv`
i get the points to plot with:

```
fsb <- fs.boundary(r0=0.1, r=1.1, l=2173)
```

if with standard graphic package i plot fsb and then i add lines i get :

```
 x11()
 plot(fsb)
lines(fsb$x,fsb$y)
```

[image]

I try now with ggplot (this is the line within a bigger code) :

```
tpdf <- data.frame(ts=fsb$x,ps=fsb$y)
ts=fsb$x
ps=fsb$y
geom_line(data=tpdf, aes(ts,ps), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

i get a messy plot: [image]

I think that i'm failing the order in geom_line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by using `geom_path`:

```
ggplot(tpdf)+
  geom_point(aes(ts,ps)) +
  geom_path(aes(ts,ps))
```

[image]

You have a very odd way of using `ggplot` I recommend you to reexamine it.

data:

```
library(mgcv)
fsb <- fs.boundary(r0 = 0.1, r=2, l=13)
tpdf <- data.frame(ts=fsb$x,ps=fsb$y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to specify the `group` parameter - for example, this

```
ggplot(tpdf) + 
  geom_point(aes(ts, ps)) +
  geom_line(aes(ts, ps, group = gl(4, 40)))
```

gives me a plot similar to the one in base R. 
[image]